# Is there any plugin to publish exam result?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I am developing a WordPress site for a school. I need to add a result publishing module on it, so that the students can get their annual exam result through the website by entering their registration number. Is there any plugin available for this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the long answer or the short answer? Okay fine I'll give you both.

Short answer, no (at least not one that I know of that does this)

Long answer, no but you can do this pretty easily by using other plugins. Here are a few ways to go about it.

1. Create a custom post type either in a custom plugin or use [Pods](http://podscms.org/) or [Magic Fields 2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magic-fields-2/) to create a custom post type that stores the usernameid and test then have them enter their user id and take them to their results page.
2. Use [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityhelp.com/gravity-forms-v1-6-is-here/) (or similar) create a page where grades can be entered then create a simple login for each user.
3. Get advice from a WordPress Developer or hire someone with the skills to accomplish your task.

Comment: +1 for the 3rd point, although I would add "...unless you are one [a developer]", since we can't make assumptions on who is going to read the answer.

Comment: as far as I can understand, You are looking for the plugin where you can add marks of the students and can display result in front end :  Here you can see :  https://wordpress.org/plugins/emarksheet/